# Find wavelength from relative permittivity and frequency

Tags: electromagnetism

If i have a EM wave with frequency 1MHZ and εr=9  in a perfect dielectric ,is it possible to find the wavelength λ and  wave propagation speed ? It seems impossible to me..

Answer (score 2):

(1) $\lambda \nu = c$

(2) $c^2 = \frac{1}{\mu_0 \epsilon_r \epsilon_0}$

Comment: A bit explanation: most materials, apart from ferromagnetic ones, have relative permeability close to 1.